# Java Application is consuming more and more Memory, which sometimes is up to 2GB,

Tags: java, memory, cpu

I have an JavaFX application, which includes a background thread used for data processing and show the result in the user interface.
I created the following code for data processing:

```
    public static void runningThread(){
    long startTime = java.lang.System.nanoTime();

    WSN wsn = new WSN(100, 100, 30, 60, 200);
    wsn.initializeNodePosition();
    wsn.alphaNodesDead = wsn.nodeNumber/2;


    BaseStation BS = new  BaseStation();                                            //the BS is created
    BS.x = 125;
    BS.y = 50;
    BS.maxRadius = 65;
    BS.energyModel = new NOEnergyModel();

    wsn.BS = BS;
    BS.wsn = wsn;



    Thread queryThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Start");

            for(int m=0; m<1000; m++){
                System.out.println(m);

                wsn.protocol    = new HEED(wsn);
                wsn.generateHomogeneousWSN(HEEDNODE.class, new MITModel(), new SimpleAggregation());
                wsn.protocol.setRadiusAndNeighbors();


                boolean running = true;
                while(running){
                    wsn.roundPerformed++;

                    wsn.protocol.election_cluster_formation();              //cluster formation
                    wsn.defineStandardCHRouting();                          //defines the routing at CH level
                    wsn.protocol.runRound();

                    System.out.println(wsn.roundPerformed);

                    if(wsn.deadNodeList.size() >= wsn.alphaNodesDead){
                        long stopTime = java.lang.System.nanoTime();

                        System.out.println("end: " + (stopTime-startTime) / 1000000000.0);

                        running = false;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    };
    queryThread.start();
}
```

The problem is after I run the application and click "Start" button to run the "runningThread()" function, the consuming of memory and CPU are higher and higher, when it reaches more than 2GB of memory and 90% of CPU, the "for(int m=0; m<1000; m++)" loop become very slow. I am clearing all the object before each single loop starts.
Does JVM will reclaims memory automatically for reuse once any of the object lose all the reference to it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symptoms you describe are strongly suggestive of a memory leak:

- Ever increasing memory utilization
- The application gets slower and slower because the GC takes longer and runs more and more often.
- Eventually, you get an `OutOfMemoryError` and the application crashes.

A memory leak typically happens when an application creates more and more objects which cannot be garbage collected because they are still reachable.

The general solution to this is to find the cause of the memory leak (which is typically a bug) and fix it.  There are lots of tools for finding memory leaks in Java programs, and StackOverflows on how to do it. on how to do it.

- Forcing the GC to run won't help.  The GC is already running ... and is not able to reclaim objects because they are still reachable.
- Increasing the heap size probably won't help either.  It just puts off the inevitable slowdown to later in your application's run.

---

> Does JVM will reclaims memory automatically for reuse once any of the object lose all the reference to it ?

Yes.

And you DON'T need to force the GC to run.

The fact that objects are not being reclaimed implies that they are still reachable.  In other words, your code that is supposed to ensure that objects become unreachable is not working.

Comment: I was running a loop and inside I was generating hundreds of objects. I put them inside a tree which is defined as globally, after processing those objects inside the tree, I did nothing except cleaning the tree. I checked the tree and it was empty. Next loop, the same procedure, generating hundreds of object and put them inside that global tree. And again and again ...

Comment: They must have been reachable from somewhere else.  Or it may have been other objects.   Using a memory profiler will help you find what the objects are and that will give you clues as to why they are leaking.

Comment: At the end, I solved this issue by re-using the existing tree (changing the properties' value of objects in that tree), but the speed of thread becomes a little slow because of iterating too many objects and changing some properties' value one by one, not as quick as generating new objects.

Answer (score 2):

The memoryleak can be anywhere in your code. Use VisualVM profiler or a build-in profiler in your IDE to find it.

Answer (score 1):

It is 'undefined' as to when the JVM garbage collection kicks in.

I think your major problem is that your inner while loop is continually testing without a pause - try adding Thread.sleep(100) inside the while loop.

Comment: It only slows down the speed, but no other help. How can I call the garbage collector ?

Comment: You can 'request' garbage collection with a System.gc() call.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM will reclaim memory for unused objects, but it won't do it until the GC process runs.  I would take a guess that `runRound` is allocating a lot of objects internally.  Chances are the GC won't have run by the next iteration of your loop, so new memory is allocated, then again, and again, etc.

Eventually it will hit whatever the JVM's ceiling is (`-Xmx` parameter) and then the GC will start to kick in a lot more aggressively to free up unused objects, but you don't really have a lot of control over when it happens.

Using a tool such as VisualVM will help you identify what your problem is.  It will show you the difference between bytes allocated, and bytes actually used.  You can also see when the GC process occurs.  VisualVM is included with the JDK.

The other alternative is that `runRound` is allocating objects that it's keeping some sort of global reference to.  Again, careful use of VisualVM should let you identify this.

Comment: yes, runRound is doing a lot of stuff, but everything is referenced to wsn.protocol. So at the beginning of each loop, I am doing wsn.protocol    = new HEED(wsn); to initialize all stuff, in this way, every object inside previous loop will lose the reference so that they will be regarded as garbage by GC. I just want run an simulation 1000 times, and get the average result.

Comment: You can suggest that it runs by calling `System.gc()`, but it's not guaranteed to actually do anything.  Beware that your strategy of creating a new instance of `NEED` each time might be counter-productive, since you are guaranteeing that it can't re-use any of its already allocated objects.  If you are able to use the same instance, it might be smart enough to re-use existing arrays, etc

Comment: Yes, at the end, I solved this issue by re-using the existing array (changing the properties' value of objects in that array), but the speed of thread becomes a little slow because of iterating too many objects and changing some properties' value one by one, not as quick as generating new objects.